# How to create custom validation helper that change the corresponsing field value in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm starting to write my own field validation helper, no matter the reason.
I want to control the value in the textbox being validated and not only render a validation message.

Is there a way to access the html control being validated from my custom extension code?

Here is a very basic beginning:
(Please don't judge the code, i simplified it for the sake of the question)

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomValidatioMessageFor<TModel, 
        TProperty>(this HtmlHelper obj, Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> 
        expression){
    string html = (string)obj.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
    html = "<div>" + /* Here goes the error message blabla... */ + "</div>";
    return new MvcHtmlString(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to control the value in the textbox being validated

Validation helpers are designed to validate the data once it is input but you need to constraint the data while it is being input. This means that you cannot achieve it using validation helpers; you need a more eager approach based on hooking into keyboard/mouse events. Also, it will be completely javascript based as on server side you don't have text boxes; you only have posted models.

Comment: So how do the MVC default validators do it?

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.net MVC framework uses [jquery-validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) to perform validation client side prior to errors being passed back to the server.  If a Validation helper's code has been hit, the data has already been submitted off the client, and the only thing the server can do is accept or deny the processing of the data.

You can write your own handlers for fields and define different rules, see the source for [jquery validation demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) for multiple examples of different ways to take action on your form fields.

Comment: But in MVC when you use server validation that fails, it puts a red border around the textbox which is being validated in addition to the validation message, how does it work there? Do they have access to the textbox somehome when doing the validation? Is there a way for me to use a similiar mechanism myself?

Comment: those are the client side validators, being handled through the jquery-validation.  if the client side validation is turned off, i.e. `$('form').validate({ ignore: 'form *'});` you will get an entirely different experience.